# get the file name from base64_decode image

Tags: php, image, laravel

Image will send from `mobile api` with `base64` type and I am trying to get the image name from `base64_decoded` image file.how can I get it?

```
$data = 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABl'
       . 'BMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDr'
       . 'EX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r'
       . '8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';
$data = base64_decode($data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
```

here is my fuction trying to get image name written with laravel

```
   public function completeProfile($session_id,$username,$fullname,$position,$image){
      $user = JWTAuth::toUser($session_id);
      $userid = $user->id;
      $img = base64_decode($image);
      if(file_put_contents(public_path().'/images/users',$img)){
          $result = $this->repository->completeProfile($userid,$username,$fullname,$position,$image);
      }
      return false;
}
```

Comment: you cannot get image name first you have to save into desired folder by using desired name

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to get the filename from base64 format, as this only contains the data that makes up the image, not it's metadata.

Answer (score 3):

I have used this code in `slim` php  framwork to save  image to desired folder

```
$img= base64_decode($val_pic);
$image_name=  "test.jpg"; /* name image*/


if( $file = fopen("folder/".$image_name, 'wb')){
            fwrite($file, $img);
            fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: if my answer solved your problem please tick/mark it @Yan Myo Aung